# Can all constraints in swift 3 be animated?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to animate a view like using the following code:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.7, delay: 0.1, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        self.AVCenterY.constant = 0.8
      }, completion: nil)
```

But it happens so fast it seems like it is not animated. On the other hand, when I animate the property alpha it is animated (it takes the 2.7 seconds to change). I used 2.7 sec to make sure the problem was that I was using a small duration time.

Comment: Don't set the constant in the animation block, set it before the animation block then call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints cannot be animated at all. It is the *act of layout* that can be animated:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.7, delay: 0.1, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
    self.AVCenterY.constant = 0.8
    theView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() // *
}, completion: nil)
```

When we animate the act of layout (or when the runtime does so), *then* any constraint changes are also automatically animated.

Note that what I animate is the *layout* of the *superview* of the view that is to move. I called it `theView` but that is just something I made up. You will need an outlet to that view so that you can get its superview, and use the name of that outlet.