# Constraint animation not working

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, constraints

I'm trying to animate the change of priority in 2 constraints, but I can't seem to make it work. My animation code it's written as the following:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        if self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority == UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh {
            self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
            self.cardHeaderBottomToBodyBottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
        } else {
            self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
            self.cardHeaderBottomToBodyBottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
        }

        self.flightInformationBodyCard.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.flightInformationBodyCard.updateConstraints()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: change the priority and call updateConstraints before calling the UIView.animate and keep only layoutIfNeeded inside the animate function

Comment: Are you sure those properties are animatable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584375/can-all-constraints-in-swift-3-be-animated this one says to make the change the call layout inside the animation block, couldnt find a non-constant example, will be interested to see if it works

Comment: It is necessary to put only layoutIfNeeded() to animation block. All other parts may be moved out. Also updateConstraints() function unnecessary as I think.

Comment: @solenoid I've worked with priorities before, and it did work. I don't know what's happening this time.

Comment: @solenoid using the superview actually worked!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I had to do was changing the layoutIfNeeded method to superview as in:

```
        if self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority == UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh {
        self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
        self.cardHeaderBottomToBodyBottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
    } else {
        self.cardHeaderBottomtoBodyTopConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
        self.cardHeaderBottomToBodyBottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
    }

    //self.flightInformationBodyCard.updateConstraints()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

        self.flightInformationBodyCard.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I've been looking for this everywhere, why my animations weren't working. needed to switch the layoutIfNeeded to the superview!